# Compute $(-18i)^{1/2}$ cannot find the $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

So as the title suggests. I cannot seem to find the argument of a complex number consisting of only the imaginary part. I have traditionally just used $\arctan \frac yx$ but with $x$ being nonexistent I am unsure of how I should proceed. I am quite certain I am missing some important conceptual underpinning that would make this all clear to me.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am also aware of De Moivres Formula, I am just having trouble with finding the Arg(z)

Comment: The argument of $-i$ is $-\pi/2+2\pi\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: could you elaborate a tad? I am sure it is correct but how did you get it? Is it the equivalent of an identity that I should just commit to memory?

Comment: If you want to see it with your formula $\mathrm{atan}(y/x)$, remember at which values the function $\mathrm{atan}$ goes to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$...

Comment: Arg((-18i)^1/2) = Arg((-i)^1/2);
Arg(-i) = 3pi/2, so Arg((-i)^1/2) = 3pi/4

Comment: $-18i=0-18i$. Can you place this point in the complex plane? What angle is there between a segment from the origin ($0+0i$) to $0-18i$ ?